# Scan file or folder with bad permissions

Tags: php, file, joomla, permissions, directory

I'd just like to see a list of files and folders where folder <> 755 and file <> 644

Is there a script that can recursively scan all files/folders on my web server for this info?

My site got hacked, a bunch of files were set to 200 permissions, its a Joomla 1.5 site, so many files/folders, will take for ever to do this manually.

Host at 1and1 and is a linux shared server

I'm looking for a PHP script

**SOLUTION (thanks Robert for info)**
For some reason on windows and linux folders return 55
I got the function for perms from http://php.net/manual/en/function.fileperms.php

```
<?php
$path = realpath('.');
$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path),RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
$c = 0;

foreach($files as $name => $f){
        $perm = file_perms($f);
        if ($perm!="644" && $perm!="755" && $perm!="55") {
            $c++;
            echo "<b>".$perm."</b> :: ";
            echo $f->getPathname()."<br>";
            if ($c==200) {exit();}
        }
}

function file_perms($file, $octal = false)
{
    if(!file_exists($file)) return false;
    $perms = fileperms($file);
    $cut = $octal ? 2 : 3;
    return substr(decoct($perms), $cut);
}
?>
```

Comment: unix command CHMOD -R

Comment: You cannot change something the process has no write access to.

Comment: are you looking for an unix command or for a php script to do this?

Comment: `tag` it also `Joomla`

Comment: If your server has been hacked, changing these back doesn't mean that you're free and clear. Read the following link: "In situations like this the problem is that you don't have control of that system any more. It's not your computer any more. The only way to be certain that you've got control of the system is to rebuild the system." http://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server

Comment: I'd like a PHP script plz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use php with [chmod()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php) function and [resursive directory iterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php)

To check file permissions you can use `fileperms()` function. It returns the file's permissions as a numeric mode. You can use [resursive directory iterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) + this checking with [fileperms()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fileperms.php) and you can set permissions with `chmod()`. With **Directory Iterator** you can also use [getPerms()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.getperms.php) method.

**Example:**

```
$path = realpath('/path/to/dic');

$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path),RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach($files as $name => $f){
    if($f->getPerms() != 775 && $f->isFile()) {
        chmod($fileinfo->getPathname(), 0775);
        echo getPathname();
    }
}
```

This will set chmod to 775 for files that have different permissions. You can also use 3 methods to check read/write/exec permmisions:

- DirectoryIterator::isExecutable() - Determine if current DirectoryIterator item is executable
- DirectoryIterator::isReadable() - Determine if current DirectoryIterator item can be read
- DirectoryIterator::isWritable() - Determine if current DirectoryIterator item can be written to

Comment: I am thinking that the question is how to find those files, not how to change the permissions

Comment: I'd like to review the affected files before manually changing them, if possible

Comment: This seems like the best approach, I'll give this a go, tx man

Answer (score 1):

You should upgrade to more recent Joomla! version as soon as possible. Otherwise, you'll face more and more successful attacks in the future, because Joomla! 1.5 has reached EOL (end of life) a long time ago.

Generally it is a good idea to use a tool like [Akeeba Admin Tools](https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/admin-tools.html), which can do exactly what you asked for, and a lot of other useful stuff to harden your Jommla! installation.

Answer (score 0):

```
find /home/*/public_html -type d -perm 755
```

Comment: You can change with your directory and specific permissions